# SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_WARNINGS'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @archivedate AS DATETIME = '20190501'; --Always use ISO 8601 format YYYYMMDD

WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP((SELECT TOP (1) COUNT(DISTINCT ratechangedate) datecount
                FROM MARS_DW.[dbo].[vw_GTMScheduledRateAndPaymentChangesWithAccountNumber_Archive]
                WHERE ArchiveDate = @archivedate AND AppliedDate > '1/2/2018'
                GROUP BY account
                ORDER BY datecount DESC)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)        
SELECT @cols = (SELECT REPLACE( '
    ,MIN( CASE WHEN index_num = <<index_num>> THEN ratechangedate END) AS [date <<index_num>>]
    ,MIN( CASE WHEN index_num = <<index_num>> THEN new_noterate END)   AS [rate <<index_num>>]' , '<<index_num>>', n)
            FROM cteTally
            ORDER BY n
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 

set @query = 
N'WITH a AS (
    SELECT a.account,
        dense_rank() OVER ( PARTITION BY a.account ORDER BY ratechangedate) AS index_num,
        ratechangedate,
        new_noterate
    FROM MARS_DW.[dbo].[vw_GTMScheduledRateAndPaymentChangesWithAccountNumber_Archive] a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM mars..vw_loans
        WHERE loanstatus <> ''bk payment plan''
        ) b ON a.account = b.account
    WHERE archivedate = @date
    )
SELECT a.Account' + @cols + N'
FROM a
GROUP BY a.Account;'


EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, N'@date datetime', @date = @archivedate;
```

That gives me this

[image]

If I go to messages I notice this warning

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(4300 row(s) affected)
```

I need to put this query into python but it complains when I do because of this error. I have tried to use

I tried `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` but I get this error message when I do this:

```
Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_WARNINGS'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: why do you need to "fix" the initial warning? Just ignore it. The thing that it is warning you about is expected and the desired behaviour in this case.

Comment: @MartinSmith I cannot run the query though in Python to push the data into a dataframe. The query itself runs find in SQL but not when you put it in Python

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx are you using a store procedure and recall it from your python ?

Comment: @iSR5 No but I was gonna try that

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx, do that, and in the store procedure, insert the results into a temp table, and then select the results from the temp table. and In your python, just call the store procedure. See if this workaround is going to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you tried to type `SET ANSI_WARNINGS off;`? More than that try to add `set nocount on;` too
I suggest that you should type it

1. as first line in your sql

```
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ...
```

2. and as first line in your dynamic query

```
set @query = 
N'
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
WITH a AS (
    SELECT a.account,
        dense_rank() OVER ( PARTITION BY a.account ORDER BY ratechangedate) AS index_num,
        ratechangedate,
        new_noterate
    FROM MARS_DW.[dbo].[vw_GTMScheduledRateAndPaymentChangesWithAccountNumber_Archive] a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM mars..vw_loans
        WHERE loanstatus <> ''bk payment plan''
        ) b ON a.account = b.account
    WHERE archivedate = @date
    )
SELECT a.Account' + @cols + N'
FROM a
GROUP BY a.Account;'
```

this will remove your messages after query execute

Comment: there is no issue with how they set the ansi warnings off. this worked hence them receiving the error `Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_WARNINGS'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.` **when it is not off they see** `Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.`

Comment: So let OP show, where in his code he has used `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;`

Comment: I set it at the begging just fyi

Comment: For 2. Could you post my whole code I tried to do what you did but I get a bunch of errors